# I am on a MacBook Air and using a guest account. I am trying to access a USB, but I can't

Tags: guest-account

Ok, so here's the deal. I have a picture, from Google Images, that I am trying to put on a flashdrive or such so I can make it the profile picture to the account I am currently logged into. I have the latest OSX and everything is up to date. I am on a Safari only guest account. Whenever I try to download anthing to the computer directly, I only get a "Safari could not download the file “Just Another Day For Arceus.mp4” because there is not enough free disk space. Try deleting documents or downloading to another disk." This of course, was trying to download a video, not the said picture. That, and when I try to right click items, the usual white bar with several items does not appear. I can access the USB, however, when I go to Google's homepage and click "Change Image" and although I can access the files already on it, I cannot add any new files. Please help if you can, and let me know if I can do anything without logging into the Admin account. Also, I am not much of a tech person, so if you try to give me pathways, I won't know what to do with them, nor how to use them.

Thank you so much in advance,

Drena The Eliatrope

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because "File Vault" is activated on your MacBook. [File Vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) is a program that comes with your Mac and encrypts your hard drive so only people with the password to do so can look at files on your Mac.
Apparently once File Vault is activated, you can only access Safari on a guest account, as stated [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2300563&seqNum=2).

> If you log in as that guest user, you don't get access to your hard
> drive; you can only access the Safari web browser and a network
> connection. Exiting Safari simply returns you to the FileVault 2
> pre-boot login screen.

This means, you cannot save e.g. images to your computer and then put them on a external drive. This is (as far as I know) because files are not uploaded directly from an USB device to the Internet: your computer performs the task of moving the file from the USB device to the hard drive and from there to the Internet.

I'm afraid as long as you can't change the settings with the Admin Account (in this case you'd have to deactivate File Vault) you cannot save files to your computer or an external drive.

What you could do instead: access your e-mail client within Safari (if you have Gmail, just go to [Gmail](http://www.gmail.com) and then right-click on the picture you want to get and choose "Copy Image URL" and then paste the URL in your e-mail and have it send to yourself (just send an e-mail to your own e-mail address) With this way, you can download it on another computer, once you access the URL of the picture.

Google's [instructions](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/118238?hl=en) for this:

> Computer
>
> Do a search on images.google.com for the image you want to find.
>
> In your browser’s address bar at the top of the page, click once
> to select the entire URL.
>
> (If you're looking for the URL of an image
> result, you need to click on the image to open up a larger version
> before selecting the URL.)
>
> Right-click the image.
> Depending on what system you’re using, select the image URL by clicking one of these:
>
> Chrome: Copy image URL
>
> Safari: Copy image address
>
> Internet Explorer: Properties > Copy the URL address shown
>
> Firefox: Copy image location

I hope this wasn't "too easy" for you and let me know if it works out!

Comment: I have already noted that I cannot right click on things, therefore I cannot use the solution you gave.

Comment: there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to right-click. Maybe your trackpad is set up in a way you don't expect?